# What is the shell script instruction to divide a file with sorted lines to small files?

Tags: file, shell, text, solaris

I have a large text file with the next format:

```
1 2327544589

1 3554547564

1 2323444333

2 3235434544

2 3534532222

2 4645644333

3 3424324322

3 5323243333

...
```

And the output should be text files with a suffix in the name with the number of the first column of the original file keeping the number of the second column in the corresponding output file as following:

```
file1.txt:

2327544589

3554547564

2323444333

file2.txt:

3235434544

3534532222

4645644333

file3.txt:

3424324322

5323243333

...
```

The script should run on Solaris but I'm also having trouble with the instruction awk and options of another instruccions like -c with cut;  its very limited so I am searching for common commands on Solaris. I am not allowed to change or install anything on the system. Using a loop is not very efficient because the script takes too long with large files. So aside from using the awk instruction and loops, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$ awk 'NF>1{print $2 > "file"$1".txt"}' input

$ cat file1.txt 
2327544589
3554547564
2323444333
```

or if you have bash available, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a b
do
    [ -z $a ] && continue
    echo $b >> "file"$a".txt"
done < input
```

output:

```
$ paste file{1..3}.txt
2327544589  3235434544  3424324322
3554547564  3534532222  5323243333
2323444333  4645644333
```

Comment: Sorry again, I cannot afford using loops, like I said in the main question, because the original file has lot of lines. I tested your loop and is taking so much time

Comment: @user2295976 - all solutions involves a loop either explicit or implicit. The loop above is as lightweight as you can get; each line in the file is visited only once, you cannot beat that! I can post a python and a perl solution if you're interested where you slurpe the file into memory... How large is your input?

Comment: Well its a large number: 499997 in a file for testing, the final file has millions, but thank you, that loop is solving the problem for now, if only I could test the awk instruction that you gave :(